# Problems using batch_update in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, sql-update

I read similar batch_update Qs but I still have issues. Thanks in advance for help! I receive error message ("One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.") for the following code:

Controller:

```
public function do_edit_page(){
    $id = $this->input->post('page_id', TRUE);
    $link_title = $this->input->post('page_link_title', TRUE);
    $link = $this->input->post('page_link_sub_title', TRUE);
    $this->content_model->update_links($id, $link_title, $link);
    $this->index();
}
```

Model:

```
public function update_links($id, $link_title, $link){
   $data = array(
        array(
            'page_id' => $id,
            'link_title' => $link_title,
            'link' => $link
        )
    );
   $this->db->update_batch('content_links', $data, $id);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the CI documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

The first parameter will contain the table name, the second is an associative array of values, **the third parameter is the where key.**

so the third parameter should be a column not data.

Comment: Thanks for that. May I ask further please. I changed third parameter now to 'page_id'. Errors are gone but it does not update. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the right parameters ? can you show me an example of the input and an example of the output query that you are looking for ?

Comment: yeah realized I have more complicated issue, as I am using foreach inside the view. I managed it to update but it updates each row with same data. I opened another more specific Q. Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979135/update-multiple-rows-with-same-id-using-forach-loop