# update_batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, updates

Here is my code that i used to update all the rows that am getting for that i used update_batch function but its not working properly

```
 public function edit_project_involved($users)
{

    foreach ($users as $v_user) {

    $data=array('involved'=>1);
    $v=$this->db->where('user_id',$v_user);
    $query=$this->db->update_batch('tbl_users',$data,$v);
    }

    if($query)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

my $users var_dump looks like this

```
C:\wamp64\www\spectra\application\models\Project_model.php:536:
array (size=3)
0 => string '40' (length=2)
1 => string '42' (length=2)
2 => string '37' (length=2)
```

am getting an error like this

```
One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.
```

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/spectra/system/database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 2010

My table looks like this

```
user_id     username        involved
    1         admin           0
    36        siraj           0
    37        faizal          0
    38        nesru           0
    40        jaseer          0
    42        maltu           0
    43        shahul          0     
    44        samsheera       0
```

var_dump($data) looks like this

```
C:\wamp64\www\spectra\application\models\Project_model.php:544:
array (size=3)
0 => 
  array (size=2)
    'user_id' => string '40' (length=2)
    'involved' => int 1
1 => 
  array (size=2)
    'user_id' => string '42' (length=2)
    'involved' => int 1
2 => 
  array (size=2)
    'user_id' => string '37' (length=2)
    'involved' => int 1
```

Comment: Define *not working properly*

Comment: @manulaiko now what you need more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems using batch\_update in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976144/problems-using-batch-update-in-codeigniter)

Comment: please help me to solve

Comment: is it code problem or codeigniter error

Answer (score 4):

You not followed the rules mentioned in documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Try this (notice `update_batch` outside of loop and how the array made)

```
foreach ($users as $v_user) {
  $data[] = array(
   'user_id' => $v_user,
   'involved'=> 1
  );
}
$query = $this->db->update_batch('tbl_users',$data,'user_id');
```

Comment: here am getting undefined index user_id

Comment: I have edited the answer with minor changes, now test and if still not work then show your `var_dump($data)` result from outside loop

Comment: show your `var_dump($data)` result from outside loop

Comment: Now what your `var_dump($query)` return. finally are you sure you kept `update_batch` outside loop? also check if there are another variable name `$data` exist if so the change variable name

Comment: yaa its outside the loop

Comment: `var_dump($query)` not returning anything

Comment: hi bro @RejoanulAlam, could you pls help my problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654976/codeigniter-batch-update-for-checkbox