# How to batch update multiple records using CodeIgniter query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have looked at the other answers on this topic and I feel that I am following the documentation, but nonetheless I am not able to update. Below is the code in my model:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$data = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $l_xAnswer) {
    if ($l_xAnswer['status'] == '1' && $l_xAnswer['client_id'] == DB_CLIENT_ID) {
        $data[] = [
            'id' => $l_xAnswer['id'],
            'status' => 2
        ];
    }
}

return $this->db->update_batch('quiz_answers', $data, 'id');
```

The $data object at this point looks as follows (var_dump):

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "20223"
    ["status"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "19165"
    ["status"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "19129"
    ["status"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

The selected records are not updating. At this point, I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Please follow the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594166/update-batch-in-codeigniter  .You can't update bulk using primary key as show in your data-set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [update\_batch in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594166/update-batch-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Are your initial values from the quiz_answers table, the same one you are updating? If not, they have to exist (the id's) to be updated. Apart from that, if that is your actual $data as shown in your var_dump - it will work. I tested it with some dummy code.

Comment: Yes, I am not updating the ID’s, I am trying to update the “status” WHERE id IN (values). According to the documentation, this is how it should work. It specifies that the id property of each sub array can be used in the where by structuring it this way. Please let me know what I missed.

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar I do not see in the documentation or the post you referenced where it says that primary key cannot be used. The primary key here should only be used in the WHERE clause of the statement. The value being updated is 'status'.

Comment: @Vincent yes we can not bulk update using primary key , so you can update through loop.

Comment: @Vincent found any solution?

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar Yes thank you. I simply went with `$this->db->where_in()` and specified the id's as a string, and executed `$this->db->update('table', ['status'=> 2]);`. I needed the PK as the reference and this method worked.

Comment: @Vincent , nice logic dear